# Java script to detect Enter key press in Mobile App

Tags: javascript, android, keycode

i wanna get key code of buttons with java script and it works just fine in IOS and PC (when i press button it gives me the key Code of the button) but it not works with android..
how can i make it work with android too?

```
function keydownFunction(event) {
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownFunction);
```

Comment: Mobile devices don't have buttons. Try the `touch` event.

Comment: but it works with IOS... the problem only with andoird

Comment: Also, the ENTER key keycode is 13.

Comment: Yeah but i dont know how can i fix with android?

Comment: Did you try setting up a `touch` event in addition to the `keydown` event? just because it works as is on iOS doesn't mean the same approach will work everwhere.